# Deploying VSTO Project to Server

Tags: deployment, ms-office, vsto

Is it possible to place an application using vsto if the office is not installed? It doesn't appear to be so, but I was wondering if anyone had a work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSTO wraps Office's Automation interfaces. Office is doing the work under the covers, so must be installed.

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

Just to compare with Web Office Extensions, did it also need Office installed on the server?

Comment: No it didn't. The web components were a seperate activeX control used as a type of viewer for embedded office content within html files I believe. Feature deprecated in Office 2007 timeframe in favour of SharePoint and Excel web services.